# Getting MPU6050 data through Arduino Micro Pro and Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, mpu6050

I have a problem with getting sensor data from MPU6050 through Bluetooth module HC-06. I am using Arduino Micro Pro. I do not have a lot of experience, so it could be some rookie mistake.

If I upload this code to Arduino, then connect via Bluetooth, I continuously receive "234" (I am using Tera Term):

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600); 
  delay(50);
}

void loop() {

  Serial1.println("234");
  delay(500); 
}
```

Also when I use this code without unplugging from PC, I correctly receive gyro and accelerometer data on serial monitor in Arduino IDE:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <I2Cdev.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

MPU6050 mpu;
int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);

   Serial.println("a");


   Wire.begin();

   Serial.println("b");

   mpu.initialize();

   Serial.println("c");
}

void loop() {
  mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);


  Serial.print("hh");
  Serial.println(ax);
  delay(20);
}
```

So all the hardware is supposedly working correctly. However, when I change all the `Serial` functions in the last example to `Serial1` and then try to get the data through Bluetooth, the Tera Term window just stays blank without any kind of data that I am aware of coming in.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no "Arduino Micro Pro". Pro Micro is not Arduino's design. [It's from SparkFun.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640)

Answer (score 0):

serial1 is for serial port of your component.

Do you plug Bluetooth uart on serial port 1?

Do you detect properly The Bluetooth module?

Comment: Not only I can detect the module, but also the first example works. I get "234" infinitely on tera term connection window.

The bluetooth is connected tx - rx and rx - tx. Between rx of bluetooth and tx of arduino is 1x resistor. Bluetooth rx also branches through 2 k resistors to ground pin.

Comment: Try Serial1.print(ax)

Comment: Ok great! Type +1 to answer :)

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why would `Serial1.print(ax)` work if `Serial1.println(ax)` doesn't?

Comment: I think because there is an error of coding-decoding from one of does module